# Using ssd_random_crop_pad operation in Tensorflow's Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, data-augmentation

I am using Tensorflow's Object Detection API to train an Inception SSD object detection model on Cloud ML Engine and I want to use the various `data_augmentation_options` as mentioned in the [preprocessor.proto](https://github.com/pkulzc/models/blob/gcp-ready-1.2/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto) file.

The one that I am currently interested in using is `ssd_random_crop_pad` operation and changing the `min_padded_size_ratio` and the `max_padded_size_ratio`.

The documentation mentioned in [preprocessor.proto](https://github.com/pkulzc/models/blob/gcp-ready-1.2/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto) says the following:

```
// Min ratio of padded image height and width to the input image's height and
  // width. Two entries per operation.
  repeated float min_padded_size_ratio = 8;

  // Max ratio of padded image height and width to the input image's height and
  // width. Two entries per operation.
repeated float max_padded_size_ratio = 9;
```

And the documentation mentioned in [preprocessor.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py) defines the function as such:

```
def ssd_random_crop_pad(image,
                        boxes,
                        labels,
                        label_scores=None,
                        multiclass_scores=None,
                        min_object_covered=(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0),
                        aspect_ratio_range=((0.5, 2.0),) * 6,
                        area_range=((0.1, 1.0),) * 6,
                        overlap_thresh=(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0),
                        random_coef=(0.15,) * 6,
                        min_padded_size_ratio=((1.0, 1.0),) * 6,
                        max_padded_size_ratio=((2.0, 2.0),) * 6,
                        pad_color=(None,) * 6,
                        seed=None,
preprocess_vars_cache=None)
```

Where the arguments for `min_padded_size_ratio` and `max_padded_size_ratio` are a tuple of the form (h, w).

However when I supply these arguments in the `config` file in the format given below:

```
data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop_pad {
      operations {
        min_padded_size_ratio: (16.0, 16.0)
        max_padded_size_ratio: (16.0, 16.0)
        random_coef: 0.5
      }
    }
  }
```

I run into the following error:

```
ps-replica-2
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 163, in <module> tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 91, in main FLAGS.pipeline_config_path) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 43, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 533, in Merge descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 587, in MergeLines return parser.MergeLines(lines, message) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 620, in MergeLines self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 635, in _ParseOrMerge self._MergeField(tokenizer, message) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 735, in _MergeField merger(tokenizer, message, field) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 823, in _MergeMessageField self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 735, in _MergeField merger(tokenizer, message, field) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 823, in _MergeMessageField self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 735, in _MergeField merger(tokenizer, message, field) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 823, in _MergeMessageField self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 735, in _MergeField merger(tokenizer, message, field) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 823, in _MergeMessageField self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 735, in _MergeField merger(tokenizer, message, field) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 870, in _MergeScalarField value = tokenizer.ConsumeFloat() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1201, in ConsumeFloat raise self.ParseError(str(e)) ParseError: 166:31 : Couldn't parse float: (
```

Can anyone help me with the format to pass the arguments to `min_padded_size_ratio` and `max_padded_size_ratio`?

Edit 1: Changed the `config` file with the following arguments:

```
ssd_random_crop_pad {
operations {
min_padded_size_ratio: 16.0
min_padded_size_ratio: 16.0
max_padded_size_ratio: 16.0
max_padded_size_ratio: 16.0
random_coef: 0.5
}
}
```

Now running into the following error:

```
Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Aspect ratio range must be non-negative: [0, 0]

[[Node: cond/RandomCropImage/SampleDistortedBoundingBox = SampleDistortedBoundingBox[T=DT_INT32, area_range=[0, 0], aspect_ratio_range=[0, 0], max_attempts=100, min_object_covered=0, seed=0, seed2=0, use_image_if_no_bounding_boxes=true, _device="/job:master/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](cond/RandomCropImage/Shape, cond/RandomCropImage/ExpandDims)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and for me the arguments was passed by:

```
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_pad_image {
      min_padded_size_ratio: 1
      min_padded_size_ratio: 1
      max_padded_size_ratio: 2
      max_padded_size_ratio: 2
      random_coef: 0.5
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
      max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
    }
```

So, maybe you should delete the `operations` altogether. Also, by my experience you shouldn't rely on tensorflow documentation too much (they tend to be broken or at least change too often sadly). Check directly your protos for options. For example my case was that argument `aspect_ratio_range` appears in [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L1116) but not in my proto so it complained. My proto contained the code:

```
message RandomCropPadImage {
  // Cropping operation must cover at least one box by this fraction.
  optional float min_object_covered = 1 [default=1.0];

  // Aspect ratio bounds of image after cropping operation.
  optional float min_aspect_ratio = 2 [default=0.75];
  optional float max_aspect_ratio = 3 [default=1.33];
```

which reveals I should use `min_aspect_ratio` and `max_aspect_ratio` in its place.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the error. I could solve it by passing the following argument :

```
data_augmentation_options {                                            
   ssd_random_crop_pad_fixed_aspect_ratio {
   operations{
        min_object_covered: 1
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.9
        max_aspect_ratio: 1.1
        min_area: 0.4
        max_area: 1
   }
   aspect_ratio: 1
}                                                                            
}
```